# How to set the property -webkit-column-gap, -webkit-column-width in webview?

Tags: android

How to set css3 property value "-webkit-column-gap, -webkit-column-width " the before loading mywebpage in webview?

How to scroll webview content(horizontal Scrolling) by using css3 multicolumn layout without changing the source HTML?